# Is there a way to stop onSelectCell when a button is clicked or disable click on certain cells?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

How could I disable click on certain cells? Also, is there a way to disable click on cells in a specific column?

I have button generated through `formatter` and its initial state is disabled. But when the disabled button is clicked (contained in a grid-cell),`onSelectCell` is called. I do not want this to happen. I want the button to act independently of the cell.

I have generated a button, in a column named `ActionIcons`:

```
var qccolmodel = function() {
        var colModel = [      
                            {name:'Name',                   index:'Name',           formatter:qcDetailsFormatterFunction.mn},
                            {name:'ReelIndex',              index:'ReelIndex',      width:28,   align:"center", formatter:qcDetailsFormatterFunction.ri},
                            {name:'FileName',               index:'FileName',       width:120,  align:"left", formatter:qcDetailsFormatterFunction.fn},
                            {name:'MediaType',              index:'MediaType',      width:70,   align:"center",formatter:qcDetailsFormatterFunction.mt},
                            {name:'QCStatus',               index:'QCStatus',       width:35,   align:"center", editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:"OK:Ok;ND:NotDone;FD:Failed"},formatter:qcDetailsFormatterFunction.qs},
                            {name:'QCComments',             index:'QCComments',     width:75,   align:"center", editable:true, formatter:qcDetailsFormatterFunction.qcm},
                            {name:'PackagingStatus',        index:'PackagingStatus',width:53,   align:"center", editable:true, edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:"ADDED:Add To Package;NOT ADDED:Remove From Package"}, resizable:false, formatter:qcDetailsFormatterFunction.ps},
                            //{name: 'ActionIcons',         index:'ActionIcons',    fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false, formatoptions:{keys:true,delbutton : false}, formatter:'actions'},
                            {name: 'ActionIcons',           index:'ActionIcons',    width:12, align:"center" , formatter:qcDetailsFormatterFunction.ai},
                            {name:'JobID',                  index:'JobID',          width:0,    hidden:true,    resizable:false,    formatter:qcDetailsFormatterFunction.id}

                       ];
        return colModel;
    };

    var qcDetailsFormatterFunction = new Object();

    function defineQCDetailsFormatterFunction() {

        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.mn = function(val,colModelOB, rowdata) {
            var innerHTML = '<span class="qc-movie-name" id="qc_' + val + '">' + val + '</span>';

            return innerHTML;
        }

        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.ri = function(val,colModelOB, rowdata) {
            var innerHTML = "<span class='qc-reel-index'>" + val + "</span>";
            return innerHTML;
        }

        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.fn = function(val,colModelOB, rowdata) {
            var innerHTML = "<span class='qc-filename'>" + val + "</span>";
            return innerHTML;
        }

        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.mt = function(val,colModelOB, rowdata) {
            var innerHTML = "<span class='qc-media-type'>" + val + "</span>";
            return innerHTML;
        }

        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.ps = function(val,colModelOB, rowdata) {
            if(!val || val == 'NOT ADDED') {
                return 'Not Added';
            } else{
                return 'Added To Package';
            }
        }

        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.id = function(val,colModelOB, rowdata) {
            var innerHTML = "<input id='qcid_" + val + "' type='radio' name='qc-jid' value='" + val + "' />";
            return innerHTML;
        }

        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.qs = function(val,colModelOB, rowdata) {
            if(!val) {
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
            } else{
                return val;
            }
        }

        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.qcm = function(val,colModelOB, rowdata) {
            if(!val.trim()) {
                return '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
            } else{
                return val;
            }
        }

        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.ai = function(val,colModelOB, rowdata) {
            var innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm save-cell" disabled data-placement="left" title="save cell">' + 
                                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
                            '</button>';
            return innerHTML;
        }


        qcDetailsFormatterFunction.gridComplete =   function(){
            var Table           =   $(this);
            GRID_UNIQUE_ID  =   QC_GRID_UNIQUE_ID;
            if(ResizeQC ==  0){
                CommonGridCompleteFunctions(Table);
                addQCDetailsPagerIcons();
                edRefreshTimerID = setGridRefreshTimer(QC_GRID_UNIQUE_ID);

                $('.save-cell').click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    if(ciRow && ciCol) {
                        $('#QCStatus').saveCell(ciRow,ciCol);
                    }       
                    $('#QCStatus').removeClass('edit-grid-state');
                    if(edRefreshTimerID == -1) {
                        edRefreshTimerID = setGridRefreshTimer('QCStatus');
                    }
                });
                ResizeQC++;
            }   
            worksOnAllGridComplete(Table);
            //$('.save-cell').tooltip();
        };

    }

    defineQCDetailsFormatterFunction();

    function addQCDetailsPagerIcons() {
        $('#QCStatus').navGrid('#gridpager_QCStatus',
                {refresh:true,refreshicon:'ui-icon-refresh',refreshtitle:'Refresh',
                 position:'left',
                 search:false,
                 add:false,
                 del:false,
                 edit:false
                })
            .navButtonAdd('#gridpager_QCStatus', {
                caption: '',
                title: 'Save Cell',
                buttonicon: 'ui-icon-disk',
                onClickButton: function(event) {
                    $('#QCStatus').saveCell(ciRow,ciCol); /* ciRow and ciCol are set in createjqgrid.js */
                    $('#QCStatus').removeClass('edit-grid-state');
                    if(edRefreshTimerID == -1) {
                        edRefreshTimerID = setGridRefreshTimer('QCStatus');
                    }
                },
                position:"last"
            });
    }
```

Comment: Your code don't contain any `onCellSelect` callback. Why it's a problem? You can use `beforeSelectRow` to prevent selection or . It should be enough to return `false` from `$('.save-cell').click` to prevent event propagation. Moreover it would be helpful if you post JSFiddle demo which reproduce the problem and if you remove some unneeded parts from your code. One have to scroll the code permanently to read it. You cab remove for example all `index` properties from `colModel` which are absolutely unneeded and just hide the information which could be really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

*But when the disabled button is clicked (contained in a grid-cell), `onSelectCell` is called*

As the dynamic button is getting rendered so you need to delegate the event to the closest static parent, in your case is the `table`:

```
$('#QCStatus').on('click', 'button:disabled', function(e){
   return false; // does -> both -> e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
});
```